# Send text then call Contact iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an emergency call app. When the user presses on the contact it calls them. Then the user has to return to the app to send the automated SMS. However I would like it that when pressed on the contact the user is taken to the message framework and once send is pressed it then calls the person. Here is the code so far.

```
- (NSString *)deviceLocation {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi, you have been contacted as there has been an emergancy. Here is the location of the caller: Latitude: %f Longitude: %f . Please call for help to that location. From Kiddy Call the iPhone app. ", locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

}



#pragma mark - PictureListMainTableCellDelegate methods
-(void)pictureListMainTableCell:(PictureListMainTableCell *)cell wantsToCallNumber:(NSString *)number
{
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        MFMessageComposeViewController *messageComposer =
        [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        NSString *message = (@"%@", [self deviceLocation]);
        [messageComposer setBody:message];
        messageComposer.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:number  , nil];
        messageComposer.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:messageComposer animated:YES completion:nil];

        NSLog(@"Texting telephone number [%@]", messageComposer);
    }
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", number];
    NSLog(@"calling telephone number [%@]", number);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self deviceLocation]);
}
```

Any solutions to this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: What is it doing as of now? What do you want it to do? Can you be more clear?

Comment: at the moment it calls the person and then you have to return to the application to be taken to the message composer

Answer (score 3):

You're doing:

```
messageComposer.messageComposeDelegate = self;
```

just define:

```
messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult
```

It will be called when someone finished editing text and you can get result out of second parameter.

```
MessageComposeResultCancelled,
MessageComposeResultSent,
MessageComposeResultFailed
```

And from this callback you can make a call.

To make a call use:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:@"123123123"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

or tel:// for calling without prompting.

Comment: thanks but that doesn't work i get unidentified identifier...?

Comment: on which line or from which class ?

Comment: on this line `messageComposer.messageComposeDelegate = messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult;`

Comment: Nooo :) Create a function -(void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result { } - in the class which is a delegate to messageComposer.

Comment: sorry im a newbie how exactly do i do that?